# Failed to locate storage for tenant

Tags: office365

I was able to call the `/subscriptions/start?contentType=Audit.SharePoint` API of Office 365 Management Activity API successfully with a valid response and validation token.
However when I tried calling `/subscriptions/content?contentType=Audit.SharePoint`
I get the following exception :

```
[ApplicationException: Failed to locate storage for tenant.]
   Microsoft.O365.EcoSystem.TableQueueCommon.Locator.EcoSystemSqlDbAccessor.GetStorageEndpoint(String tenantId, Category category, StorageAccountType contentType, Boolean forceToRefreshStorageSettings, Boolean isTestHookEnabled) in e:\chicago\sources\Dev\Compliance\src\EcoSystem\DataFeedInfra\TableQueueCommon\BlobStorageLocator\EcoSystemSqlDbAccessor.cs:212
   Microsoft.O365.EcoSystem.TableQueueCommon.Locator.EcoSystemSqlDbAccessor.GetStorageEndpoint(String tenantId, Category category, StorageAccountType contentType, Boolean isTestHookEnabled) in e:\chicago\sources\Dev\Compliance\src\EcoSystem\DataFeedInfra\TableQueueCommon\BlobStorageLocator\EcoSystemSqlDbAccessor.cs:148
   Microsoft.O365.EcoSystem.DataFeed.ApiUtility.EndRequest(String Message, Exception ee) in e:\chicago\sources\Dev\Compliance\src\EcoSystem\DataFeedInfra\PartnerSubscription\SubscriptionServiceRole\Common\Common.cs:212
   Microsoft.O365.EcoSystem.DataFeed.GlobalExceptionLogger.Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context) in e:\chicago\sources\Dev\Compliance\src\EcoSystem\DataFeedInfra\PartnerSubscription\SubscriptionServiceRole\Common\Exceptions.cs:79
   System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionLogger.LogAsync(ExceptionLoggerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +15
   System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.CompositeExceptionLogger.LogAsync(ExceptionLoggerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +137
   System.Web.Http.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +1075
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +144
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +84
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +49
   System.Web.Http.WebHost.<ProcessRequestAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext() +594
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +144
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +84
   System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar) +98
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

Can some one please help me out with this?

Comment: I need help on this. How did you subscribe? Can you please show me the request you made?

Comment: here's my question >>> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583795/office365-unauthorized-response-when-accessing-the-management-activity-api

Answer (score 1):

During this limited preview period for the API, all subscriptions are created in the disabled state, which means that content cannot be retrieved.  The /content operation should have returned an error indicating that the subscription is not currently enabled.  We'll get that fixed.

And thanks for getting an early start using the API!  If you haven't already, you can signup for the preview at the link below. We're currently limiting participation, so signing up does not guarantee access to content, but are working to open up the preview more widely as soon as possible.

Cheers,
Tom

http://dev.office.com/programs/managementactivityapi