# Office365: Unauthorized response when accessing the management activity api

Tags: office365, azure-management-api

I am having trouble accessing the management activity API that has recently been rolled out. Though I believe I have correctly configured my app

[image: AppConfig]

[image: Permissions Page during Oauth]

Yet when I make the following API call

**POST**

```
https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/<tenantId>/activity/feed/subscriptions/start?contentType=Audit.SharePoint
```

**BODY**

```
{
"webhook" : {
"address": "<myServerURL>",
"authId": "o365activityapinotification",
"expiration": ""
}
```

}

**RESPONSE**

```
401
{
    "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

### Update 1

I successfully registered the webhook (don't know what the issue was but it has registered my webhook now)

```
{
"contentType": "Audit.Sharepoint",
"status": "disabled",
"webhook": {
    "authId": "o365activityapinotification",
    "address": "<myserverurl>",
    "expiration": null,
    "status": "enabled"
}
}
```

is the response I got. Now my question is why is the status **disabled**?
I did bunch of changes but no Push has been received, I believe this disabled state here is the reason. Any help?

Comment: Can you please let me know the authentication process for Management API?

Comment: I use Client Credentials Flow for access tokens. I pass "https:// manage.office.com" as my resource and get an access token against it. The details can be found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/dn707383.aspx

Comment: Thanks for you help. I am getting error: "Specified tenant ID  is incorrectly configured in the system.". I have registered for preview program and took the enable API and preview surveys available on dashboard. Any idea on this?

Comment: The tenant and the app for that tenant must be registered. (Say your tenant is abc.com, and you have an app called myApp created through this tenant, then you need to register both of these and then use this app. I think there is a confirmation or something that you receive. Otherwise I think the error would persist.)

Comment: Where and how to register?

Comment: You have to have subscribed to their early access/preview program (you must have the invite, otherwise it's not possible I believe) You can leave a question to their support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API is in preview state so when you subscribe, it's in DISABLED state and you have to ask MSFT guys to enable it for you (provided you had an invite to the early access)
My subscription is enabled now and I'm getting the PUSH notifications for the tenant level changes.